# Запятая «потому что»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, союзы

Нужна ли запятая в предложении «Сумма увеличивается при оплате как раз потому что Вы ввели номер телефона, и скидка стала неактуальной»?

Comment: Думаю, вам все-таки придется изложить контекст (всю ситуацию). Иначе возникают совершенно фантастические предположения о смысле подобного действа.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая **нужна**: предложение - сложноподчинённое, а поскольку придаточное предложение имеет значение *причины*, она ставится *после слова "потому"* (с разделением союза потому что):

> Сумма увеличивается при оплате как раз потому, что Вы ввели номер
>   телефона, и скидка стала неактуальной.

https://russkiiyazyk.ru/punktuatsiya/zapiataia-stavitsia-pered-potomu-chto-ili-posle.html

Однозначности этого варианта расположения запятой способствует присутствие акцентирующего на причине выражения "как раз" (факт "увеличения суммы" собеседнику известен, а его причину ему поясняют). Без этого выражения возможен был бы и второй вариант расположения запятой - в случае, когда собеседнику *впервые сообщают* об увеличении суммы и одновременно говорят о причине. Расположение запятой соответсвует и речевой паузе.

Вторая запятая (перед "и") нужна ввиду причинной связи между введением номера и актуальностью скидки.

Comment: *Вторая запятая (перед "и") нужна ввиду причинной связи между введением номера и актуальностью скидки* - как сие понимать? А правило об однородности придаточных уже не действует?

Comment: Тут нет однородных придаточных.

Comment: Если третье — следствие второй части, то необходимо тире (по правилам). Но можно трактовать и как однородные придаточные: сумма увеличивается из-за введения номера телефона и неактуальности скидки. Но это хуже, так как там явно одно вытекает из другого.

Answer (score 1):

Сумма увеличивается при оплате как раз потому, что Вы ввели номер телефона — и скидка стала неактуальной.

Я бы тире ещё поставил между частями сложносочинённого предложения.

---

Вот такое имею понимание этой конструкции. Я бы так сделал:

***"Сумма увеличилась при оплате как раз потому, что Вы ввели номер телефона — и скидка стала неактуальной".***

1. Глагол в главном предложении сделал бы совершенным видом (*не увеличивается, а увеличилась*) плюс между вторым и третьим предложением поставил бы тире.
2. Значение всей конструкции: *"Сумма при оплате оказалась больше ожидаемой* (отчего, почему?) *потому* (наречие указывает на причину), *что..."* — вот дальше придаточное конкретизирует это местоименное наречие причины, которое мы вырвали из состава союза и сделали членом главного предложения. Конкретизация по смыслу: *вы ввели номер телефона, это каким-то образом отменило действовавшую для вас скидку — и именно поэтому сумма увеличилась при оплате.*

Интереснее другое:

3. Предложение *"Вы ввели номер телефона — и скидка стала неактуальной"* — это сложносочинённое предложение с первой частью — причиной, второй частью — следствием.

Это сложносочинённое предложение будет фактически таким *цельным придаточным причинным предложением* к главному "Сумма увеличилась при оплате как раз потому".

Ещё раз: это сложносочинённое предложение в виде единого придаточного предложения!

***"Сумма увеличилась при оплате как раз потому*** (вводим причину в виде сложносочинённого предложения)***, что Вы ввели номер телефона — и скидка стала неактуальной.***

4. Это именно что сложносочинённое предложение в виде единой придаточной конструкции, а не два однородных придаточных предложения, поскольку попытка представить тут два однородных придаточных приведёт к:

*"Сумма увеличивается при оплате, потому что Вы ввели номер телефона и потому что скидка стала неактуальной"*

Как будто отдельно сумма увеличилась от введения номера и отдельно от ставшей неактуальной скидки. Странновато это будет звучать.

5. Короче, это не две раздельные причины одной ситуации: это сложносочинённое предложение с первой частью - причиной, второй частью - следствием; а **всё** это вкупе есть составная причина того следствия, что в главной части.  А тире-то и нужно поставить для того, что подчеркнуть следственный характер второй части сложносочинённого, чтобы выпуклее был смысл: *вы ввели (и что случилось?) - и скидка потеряла актуальность.*

Кроме того, есть более важная вещь:

Если  поставить запятую:

*Сумма увеличилась при оплате как раз потому, что Вы ввели номер телефона(,) и скидка стала неактуальной.*

то может даже создаться впечатление, что причиной является только второе предложение, а третье предложение будет будто бы связано с первым предложением сочинением.

То есть *"Сумма увеличилась при oплате по такой-то причине, и скидка стала неактуальной"*. То есть в сочинении находятся не второе и третье, а первое и третье. А придаточное - только второе.

Так вот, тире между вторым и третьим позволяет данной непонятности избежать и представить второе и третье предложения как единую причину предложения первого.

Comment: Не мешало бы объяснить ход мысли и аргументировать.

Comment: Объяснил в ответе.

Comment: Не вижу даже намека на какое-то объяснение. Хотя бы предположение, кто ввел номер, куда, в какой ситуации, что за скидка... То есть выбрал человек, предположим телефон по акции - пока шел на кассу ввел номер - скидка стала неактуальной? И вы ещё спрашиваете, почему ситуация абсурдна?

Comment: А у тебя есть что-то, кроме "это абсурдно"?

Answer (score 0):

Запятая, о которой вы спрашиваете, безусловно нужна.
А вот в отношении корректности самой фразы - есть большие сомнения. Её совершенно необходимо переформулировать, ситуация выглядит абсурдной.

Причем речь не только о понимании самой фразы, запятая перед "и" может зависеть от смысла.

Comment: Почему ситуация абсурдна?

Comment: @ЛиХонг - чтобы читающий не чувствовал себя идиотом. Что за вопрос такой?

Comment: *Почему ситуация абсурдна?* - потому что имеет все признаки абсурда. Спросите еще, почему масло масленое. Вы можете без контекста объяснить, что происхот на самом деле? Покупатель вводит номер телефона (куда, зачем?) и у него теряется какая-то скидка?

Comment: А зачем объяснять без контекста? Может, автор вставит это предложение в середину своего текста - там ситуация и прояснится. Вопрос же был не о семантике, а о пунктуации.

Comment: Это не ко мне вопрос. Если вы умудрились дать ответ по пунктуации, не понимая смысла, то это ваши проблемы. Я так не умею.

Comment: Мне кажется, я понял смысл высказывания.

Comment: Ну так изложили бы давно, как поняли. А то движок уже ругается.

Comment: Изложил в ответе.

Comment: Пунктуация в данном предложении как раз зависит от СЕМАНТИКИ. Если убрать лексическое наполнение предложения, то такая грамматическая структура двойственная, то есть предложение (3) может быть однородным или неоднородным по отношению к предложению (2). И в данном случае выбор варианта зависит от смысла. Поэтому неверно следующее высказывание участника: "Вопрос же был не о семантике, а о пунктуации". Без контекста содержание неясно,  тогда о чем вообще здесь говорить? Вопрос  следовало бы закрыть.

Answer (score 0):

*Сумма увеличивается при оплате как раз потому, что Вы ввели номер телефона, и скидка стала неактуальной.*

Если у автора вопроса стоит запятая перед "и", но сомнений в ее постановке нет (в силу ему известного контекста), значит, часть после "и" он не считает однородным придаточным.

Часть после запятой допустимо рассматривать как вторую часть сложносочиненного предложения или как присоединение.

(Знаками препинания выделяются не только присоединительные члены предложения, но и присоединительные предложения: Цветы всё дорогие, и где он их взял?)

Ну а запятая перед "что" необходима, так как одним из условий расчленения сложного союза является наличие перед союзом частиц (усилительных, ограничительных и др.): Он разрешил молчание разве только для того, чтобы журить своих дочерей.

Comment: _Ну а запятая перед "что" необходима..._ — а ее-то и нет.